# Does apache storm allow the processing of volumunous files stored on HDFS?

Tags: hadoop, apache-storm

Does apache storm allow the processing of volumunous files stored on HDFS ?

knowing that my goal is to have a real time response  (seconds or miliseconds),

or apache storm is only dedicated to streaming process !!

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storm is only for streaming (as opposed to batch processing), but if I'm understanding you correctly, you want to read files from HDFS and process them?

The storm-hdfs module has a spout (topology data source). It might do what you want.

https://github.com/apache/storm/tree/master/external/storm-hdfs#hdfs-spout

Comment: it's great, that's exactly what I was looking for, so the Hdfs spout is intended to allow feeding data into Storm from a HDFS directory. It will actively monitor the directory to consume any new files that appear in the directory. so there is a possibility to use apache storm without a stream but only to have a quick time processing ?

Comment: Yes, but please read the note starting with "Hdfs spout assumes that the files being made visible to it in the monitored directory are NOT actively being written to".